# Build a Table using HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

I am unable to add a col span paragrapher in my table and under it put the actual table value

You can vizualize what I am trying to do in the pic

[image: Demo]

```html
<table>
  <thead>

    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Username</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td>
        WHATEVER TEXT
      </td>
      <tr>
        <td>He</td>
        <td>He</td>
        <td>He</td>
      </tr>

    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add another `td` for the `#` column, and then use `colspan="4"` on the description cell:

```css
th, td, tr {
  border-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
  text-align: center;
}

tr {
  border-width: 0 1px;
}

th {
  border-width: 1px 0;
}

td {
  border-width: 0 0 1px;
}

td[colspan] {
  border: none;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>

    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Username</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td colspan="4">
        WHATEVER TEXT
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>He</td>
      <td>He</td>
      <td>He</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: And move the last `</tr>` up to right after the `</td>` from "WHATEVER TEXT." (Most browsers will fix it automatically, but it has the potential to really mess stuff up.)

Comment: @Skylar - missed that one :)

Comment: It still sees it as two rows... I want a single row.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> <td colspan = "value">table content...</td>
> ```

This is the syntax for adding colspan attribute to the tables in html

**read this for further queries**

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/html-colspan-attribute/